# Camera flash remains lit after taking a picture

Tags: android, flutter, camera

Once the camera flash is triggered by taking a photo (FlashMode auto or always), it will not turn off again. The flash LED stays lit like a torch, even when taking another picture with FlashMode.off.
It will stay lit untill you manually trigger something that turns it off.
I have tried this on **OnePlus 9R** with the following versions:

- camera:
  version: "0.10.5"
- camera_android:
  version: "0.10.8+1"
- camera_avfoundation:
  version: "0.9.13+1"
- camera_platform_interface:
  version: "2.5.0"
- camera_web:
  version: "0.3.1+3"

There is a workaround which I cannot use in my production app, i.e., set flash mode to torch, and return it to always off.

This issue has been opened for more than a year on Github:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97501

For reproducible code kindly checkout the link above.

Can anyone please tell what to do in this case? This is a major feature for the flutter camera package which I think should have been fixed early.